# jquery clone - change button value

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to change button value after cloning with no success.

HTML code:

```
<ul id="list">    
</ul>

    <div id="wrapper">
      <table id="table1" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="171"><input type="button" name="btn" id="num" value="1"  padding='0'/></td>

          <td width="423"><label>Από:
            <input type="text" name="startpoli" id="startpoli" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <table id="table2" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="172">&nbsp;</td>
          <td width="422"><label>Προς:
            <input type="none" name="finalpoli" id="finalpoli" />
          </label></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
```

Script:

```
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
for(var n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
   var clone = $(er).clone();
   $(clone).find('#num').attr('id','num'+n);
   var id_num = 'num'+n;  
  $('#id_num').val(n);
  $('li').append(clone);
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li);
```

Changing `#id_num` value doesn't succeed neither using `attr('value',n)`  nor 
`prop('value',n)`. Where am I wrong;

Comment: i'm not sure but its seems something is wrong here :  clone = $(er).clone(); the clone variable is already Jquery Object  is not necessary to use $ again , replace "$(clone).find('#num') to clone.find('#num')

Comment: I replace it but nothing changed

Comment: This is wrong selector: `$('#id_num')` it should be `$('#' + id_num')` **but** anyway element isn't in DOM at time you are trying to change its value. BTW, your HTML markup is still invalid, getting duplicate IDs `wrapper`. So you could use instead: `$(clone).find('#num').attr({id:'num'+n, value: n});`

Comment: I made the change but its weird: first button gets value '1', second value '2' and third value '2' also!!

Comment: It would set value regarding `n`, so... I'm just wondering why are you setting so many IDs in HTML markup? This makes all your cloning logic very hard to hanlde regarding HTML validity. BTW, this ` $('li').append(clone);` should be `$(li).append(clone);`. In fact there is too many things wrong in your snippet

Comment: I'm trying to create a listview with many components. Tha't why i have somany IDs. But '1','2','2';

Comment: Thanks Wolff. Your last proposal made my code run. Sorry for all code errors. Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution:

Step 1: Change elements having `id`s to have `class`es. If you clone an element, make sure that its subtree will not contain `id`s, since then you duplicate `id`s, resulting in invalid html. Suggestion:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <table class="table1" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="171"><input type="button" name="btn" class="num" value="1"  padding='0'/></td>

      <td width="423"><label>Από:
        <input type="text" name="startpoli" class="startpoli" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table class="table2" width="600" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="172">&nbsp;</td>
      <td width="422"><label>Προς:
        <input type="none" name="finalpoli" class="finalpoli" />
      </label></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Step 2: Let's look at the script:

```
var er = document.getElementById('wrapper'); 
for(var n=0;n<3;n++){
  var li = document.createElement("li");
   var clone = $(er).clone();
   $(clone).find('#num').attr('id','num'+n);
   var id_num = 'num'+n;  
  $('#id_num').val(n);
  $('li').append(clone);
  document.getElementById('list').appendChild(li); 
  }
```

You do not need to get the element by `id`, since it does not have an `id` anymore. You should not create the `li` into the document. You should do it into the `list` `ul`. You should no longer find an element having an `id` of `num`, but rather an element having the `class` of `num`. You should make sure you are using the right selector and you are not referencing to a variable name hard-coded as a string. You should not append clone to all `li` elements, but to the `li` element you have just defined. Write structured code in the future and debug if something seems to be fishy.

Suggestion:

```
//I assume that you do this when a single wrapper element exists
var er = $('.wrapper'); 
for(var n=0;n<3;n++){
    //I create the li and add it to list as empty element. I will have it as a variable in the future
    var li = $("#list").append("<li></li>").find("li:last");
    //Cloning of er. It is a jQuery object already, so the $() is unnecessary
    var clone = er.clone();
    //I assumed that you do not need an id here, but if you need one, it can be easily added. For the sake of simplicity, I have set the value solely
    clone.find('.num').val(n);
    //I add the parsed clone to the newly created li
    li.append(clone);
}
```

Step 3: Think about your design. Do you really want to have an html outside the `list` and `clone` it inside the `list`? Isn't it too obstructive for a solution?

Comment: Nice explanation Lajos

Comment: @ringo, I am glad I could help. Also, another minor optimization. There was a line of $(clone).find('.num').val(n); in the initial solution. I have removed the $() from there as well, since it is unnecessary, as clone is a jQuery object already. It is a minor improvement, but we want to achieve the absolute best here.